# Change list icons dynamically during drop down

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multi-tiered list of the structure below. I know how to change icons dyamically, but due to the structure of the list, the top tiered list will not change dynamically. I need a way to reference the very first ul from the click event on the p class='handle' . Full set up JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbfd/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.drawer').hide();
    $('.handle').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().not(this).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

What I need is a reference to the parent `ul`.

The list structure is UL LI P(clickable) UL LI P(clickable 2nd tier)

the i cannot get the first UL to change when I click on the `<P>`. Subsequent ones will change

Something like

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded');
```

Comment: Instead of `.parent().children().not(this)` you can just use `siblings()`

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful! Do you know the relationship between the top ul and the p tag?

Comment: Yes try `.closest('ul')` this would give you a first ancestor matching a selector that is `ul`.

Comment: Unfortunately the closest ul is the one below it. What I want to do is change the icon of the very first clickable link, but I can't get it to change for the life of me. I have the subsequent ones working.

Comment: `closest` is traversing up the tree look at the fiddle provided in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.closest('ul')` this would give you a first ancestor matching a selector that is `ul`. Here is a sligtly updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbfd/1/), but I think you should tidy up the html some more.

Comment: Your code really helped. I think also my css structure needed work as well. thanks!

Comment: One thing though, when I start to get into third tiers, the third clickable tier undoes the previous icon change